# jquery - set img src to image already loaded by browser - causing an image reload in Safari

Tags: jquery

I'm using this javascript code to set an image src to the image src of an existing image:

```
var src = $('#thumbnailImg' + pageNum).attr('src');
$('#mainAppImageImg').attr('src', src);
```

In Firefox and IE this works as intended - the image uses the existing image and doesn't request the image again from the server.

In Safari, it is causing the image to be reloaded from the server. I think this is because I'm doing something wrong with the image headers the server is returning but this is not a subject I know a lot about.

You can see this in action here: http://www.las.si/tryitout.php.

Comment: By default, the image will be reloaded, you can use sprite to prevent reloading images.

Comment: You cannot set image width and height using sprite

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. @Dev Couple of follow-ons: #1 I thought by default the browser would try the cache for the image. #2 what do you mean by using a sprite?

Comment: See http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/exactly-how-to-use-css-sprites/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said by Dev:

> By default, the image will be reloaded

You should force server to cache image using .htaccess file on your images folder:

```
Header unset Pragma
Header set Cache-Control "public, max-age=10000, must-revalidate"
```

This way, safari and chrome will reuse your browser cache.

You could search too for encoding your image in base64, server side or client side using canvas element.